# Best way to store views / stats in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, view, archive, statistics

I'm working no a site which stores individual page views in a 'views' table:

```
CREATE TABLE `views` (
  `view_id` bigint(16) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `user_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `view_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `view_referrer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `view_date` date NOT NULL,
  `view_created` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`view_id`),
  KEY `view_url` (`view_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

It's pretty basic, stores user_id (the user's id on the site), their IP address, the url (without the domain to reduce the size of the table a little), the referral url (not really using that right now and might get rid of it), the date (YYYY-MM-DD format of course), and the unix timestamp of when the view occurred.

The table, of course, is getting rather big (4 million rows at the moment and it's a rather young site) and running queries on it are slow.

For some basic optimization I've now created a 'views_archive' table:

```
CREATE TABLE `views_archive` (
  `archive_id` bigint(16) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `view_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `view_count` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  `view_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`archive_id`),
  KEY `view_url` (`view_url`),
  KEY `view_date` (`view_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This ignores the user info (and referral url) and stores how many times a url was viewed per day.  This is probably how we'll generally want to use the data (how many times a page was viewed on a per day basis) so should make querying pretty quick, but even if I use it to mainly replace the 'views' table (right now I imagine I could show page views by hour for the last week/month or so and then show daily views beyond that and so would only need the 'views' table to contain data from the last week/month) but it's still a large table.

Anyway, long story short, I'm wondering if you can give me any tips on how to best handle the storage of stats/page views in a MySQL site, the goal being to both keep the size of the table(s) in the db as small as possible and still be able to easily (and at least relatively quickly) query the info.  I've looked at partitioned tables a little, but the site doesn't have MySQL 5.1 installed.  Any other tips or thoughts you could offer would be much appreciated.

Comment: umm, doesn't your server have an access log which already keeps all this data? There are plenty of log viewers/summarizers out there for web access logs. Is there a compelling reason not to use one of them?

Comment: What's the purpose of the view_created column?

Comment: The purpose of the view_created column, MicWafflestix, would be used if I wanted to show views hourly (say how many times an article was viewed each hour today).  I suppose I could use DATETIME instead of the INT(10) timestamp, but I'm not sure that'd help me out a great deal.

Comment: then I'd probably also consolidate the view_date and view_created (somewhat confusing nomenclature there) into a single DATETIME column.  Native types are always a good idea in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to have a table just for pages, and have the user views have a reference to that table.  Another possible optimization would be to have the user IP stored in a different table, perhaps some session table information.  That should reduce your query times somewhat.  You're on the right track with the archive table; the same optimizations should help that as well.

Comment: I like this idea.  Seems like some pretty basic, solid optimization of data structure (as opposed to upgrading mysql or using a nosql table or some other such big change I feared I'd have to make).  I've also just discovered the INET_ATON() function in MySQL which might help me reduce the size of storing the IP address (can use INT instead of VARCHAR).  For the short term, anyway, I think the solutions you mentioned will go a long way in fixing my problems.  Thanks.

Comment: @Charlie: you're welcome.  At large scales, the little optimizations really begin to make a big difference; at the same time, some of the really complex optimizations just don't give the return that's often expected.  I find going for the simple, straightforward optimizations first is usually what gets me 90% of the way to a good solution, if not all the way there.

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL's Archive Storage Engine**

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html

It is great for logs, it is quick to write, the one downside is reading is a bit slower. but it is great for log tables.

Comment: I glanced at that a little bit the other day.  Seems interesting, but it's not 'supported' (checked via SHOW ENGINES; query) on my current MySQL installation. I'll ask the hosting people to turn it on or whatever and play around with it.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application is a blog and you want to keep track of views for your blog posts, you will probably have a table called `blog_posts`.  In this table, I suggest you create a column called "views" and in this column, you will store a static value of how many views this post has.  You will still use the `views` table, but that will only be utilized to keep track of all the views (and to do checks if they are "unique" or not).

Basically, when a user visits a blog post post, it will check the `views` table to see if it should be added. If so, it will also increment the "views" field in the corresponding row for the blog post in `blog_posts`.  That way, you can just refer to the "views" field for each post to get a quick peek at how many views it has.  You can take this a step further and add redudancy by setting up a CRON job to re-count and verify all the views and update each `blog_posts` row accordingly at the end of the day.  Or if you prefer, you can also perform a re-count on each update if accuracy to-the-second is *key*.

This solution works well if your site is read-intensive and you are constantly having to get a count of how many views each blog post has (again, assuming that is your application :-))